# is it possible to use if then condition in mongo db validation?

Tags: mongodb, json-schema-validator, mongodb-compass

on mongo db compass I'd like to use a validation schema but on of my properties is an enum, depending on this field another field can be toggled I was able to do this using JSON schema but it dosen't seems to be working on mongoDB compass why ?

```
{
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    type: {
      enum: ['teacher', 'student']
    },
    firstname: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    lastname: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    login: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    pwd: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    "if": {"properties": {"type": {"const": "student"}}},
    "then": {"properties": {classes: {type: "array"}}}
  },
  required: [
    'type',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'login',
    'pwd',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/) indicates that it is using draft 4:

```
JSON Schema object is formatted according to draft 4 of the JSON Schema standard.
```

The [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html) site says these conditionals are new in draft 7:

```
New in draft 7 if, then and else keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

let validator = new Validator(req.body, {
password: "requiredIf:is_login_user,1",
});

Comment: Hello juli, I'v very glad that for your answer. I would suggest you to format your text using the rich stackoverflow features and also add some references that support your answer.